# Can I make a config for my java program?

Tags: java

Is it possible to make a config to interact with my java application?Say I wanted to ping the ip but I wanted to do this through a config.yml.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to write a config and use it in a Java program.

One of the easiest ways to start with is to write your config file in Java's properties format (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).